# "Listen to me play the flute" vs "listen to me playing the flute"

Tags: verbs, gerund-vs-infinitive

I see this expression "He listens to me play the flute".
Is it correct ? And what about ""He listens to me playing the flute".
What is the current form of this expression.
I didn't find the answer either in dictionaries or grammar books.
Thank you.

Comment: They mean virtually the same thing, but carry marginally different nuances. There are circumstances in which I would say *I watched my nephew play football*, and others in which I might say *playing football*. If it was an organised match, for example, I might be more inclined to the latter. Equally *he listens to me playing the flute* suggests to me as though it was something that was happening anyway, *...play the flute* suggests something I may be doing deliberately for his benefit. But I would be interested to hear what others say (or *are saying*) on the matter.

Comment: Incidentally, I would be surprised if this is not a duplication - I feel sure it will have been discussed before.

Comment: The answer of WS2 6 hours ago solved my problem, but I don't know how to end my question. Can anyone help me ?